# The intersection of two Turing-decidable languages is Turing-decidable

Tags: algorithm, proof, turing-machines

Prove the intersection of two Turing-decidable languages is Turing-decidable. (Given algorithms to decide each language, describe an algorithm to determine if a string belongs to the intersection.)

I know that a language is Turing-decidable if there is an algorithm to decide membership.  However, I am not sure where to start with this proof.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you better ask here http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Start by pondering the definition of intersection.

Comment: @LorenzoPeña [cstheory.se] is for research-level questions. You mean [cs.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It is a question about the theory of computation. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define what the intersection is. It is the set of all strings that are members of both languages.

As both languages are turing decidable means that there exist such algorithm for each. You need to prove that using those algorithms you can obtain a new one that decides membership of strings in the intersection.

Hint: an algorithm that answers yes if and only if the string is in both languages.